# how to append data in mongo db using rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `rails 4.1.8` along with `ruby 2.1.2p95` and `mongo-2.0.4` gem to    connect to `mongo db v3.0.3`. I have read this [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/) but it doesn't provide how do we append the data in the existing row of a document. Also, can anyone provide the any other link of document which provide the extensive syntax to connect to mongo from rails.

following code will not append the data, rather it will create a new row:

```
 mongo_con.find(:chatid => 5678).update_one('$set' =>  {:chat => 'this is  are you'})
```

Code :

```
require 'mongo'
db = Mongo::Client.new([ '192.168.56.102:27017' ], :database => 'stackoverflow')
```

After inserting the following row :

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("55698e906e6172193f000001"), "id" : 5678, "message" : "Hey, how are you", "type" => 1, "timestamp" => 4567723456789 }
```

I want to append this row in the previous one:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5561d03f7979393062b18bf9"), "id" : 5678, "message" : "I am good", "type" => 2, "timestamp" => 654313687989 }
```